# Document write to document get element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and I want this to get into my paragraph with id output with

But I don't get any output when I'm doing it that way.

Here's the code, I want to change all `document.write` to `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = blablabla;`

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JavaScript</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background-color: black;
        color:springgreen;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="output"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var names, i, next;
    names = new Array();
    i = 0;
    do {
        next = prompt("Please enter your name");

        if (next > " " && next != "undefined") names[i] = next;
        i++
    }
     while (next > " " && next != "undefined");
   document.write("<h2>" + (names.length) + " names written</h2>");
   document.write("<ol>");
   for (i in names) {
        document.write("<li>" + names[i] + "<br>")
   }
   document.write("</ol>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using document.write, you'll want to append each part to a variable:

```
var outputHTML = "";
outputHTML += "<h2>"; // etc
```

Then set your content with `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputHTML;`

Comment: Can you give me an example directly from my code so I could understand a bit better?

Comment: `outputHTML += "<h2>" + (names.length) + " names written</h2>";`

Answer (score -1):

```
  var names, i, next;
  // This syntax is preferred
  names = []

  // No need to use a counter here
  do {
    next = prompt("Please enter your name");

    if (next) {
      names.push(next);
    }
  }
  while (next !== "");  // Loop until an empty string/blank input

  var out = [];
  out.push("<h2>" + (names.length) + " names written</h2>");
  out.push("<ol>");
  for (i in names) {
    out.push("<li>" + names[i] + "<br>");
  }
  out.push("</ol>");

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out.join("");
```